# Unable to automatically step into server. unable to Determine a stopping location. verify symbols not found

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm using Unit Testing project solution to test the WebService. When I start Debug the method in the unit test solution

I Got this error : Unable to automatically step into server. unable to Determine a stopping location. verify symbols not found. Symbol not found.

Comment: Is your WebService built in Debug Mode?